# Conditional parameter in Cruisecontrol.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, conditional-operator, conditional-statements

Is there any way to mix up the 'AND' and 'OR' operators in Cruisecontrol.net 1.6? My if condition goes like this:

```
if ((A="a" && a="a") || (B="b" && b="b"))
{
    //Task to be done
}
```

Same thing when written in CC (The OR part):

```
<conditional>
    <conditions>
        <orCondition>
            <conditions>
                <compareCondition value1="A" evaluation="equal" value2="a" />
                <compareCondition value1="B" evaluation="equal" value2="b" />
            </conditions>
        </orCondition>
    </conditions>
    <tasks>
        <!--Task to be done-->
    </tasks>
</conditional>
```

and when written in CC with the AND part:

```
<conditional>
    <conditions>
        <andCondition>
            <conditions>
                <compareCondition value1="a" evaluation="equal" value2="a" />
                <compareCondition value1="b" evaluation="equal" value2="b" />
            </conditions>
        </andCondition>
    </conditions>
    <tasks>
        <!--Task to be done-->
    </tasks>
</conditional>
```

I want to write both of these as a single conditional operation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out myself... :)

```
<conditional>
    <conditions>
        <orCondition>
            <conditions>
                <andCondition>
                    <conditions>
                        <compareCondition value1="A" evaluation="equal" value2="a" />
                        <compareCondition value1="a" evaluation="equal" value2="a" />
                    </conditions>
                </andCondition>
                <andCondition>
                    <conditions>
                        <compareCondition value1="B" evaluation="equal" value2="b" />
                        <compareCondition value1="b" evaluation="equal" value2="b" />
                    </conditions>
                </andCondition>
            </conditions>
        </orCondition>
    </conditions>
    <tasks>
        <!--Task to be done-->
    </tasks>
</conditional>
```